# for loop not executing using Python console

Tags: python

I have this script to load CSV data to 2D array ( I hope... :)  )

```
with open("csv") as textFile:
    lines = [line.strip().split(",") for line in textFile]
```

Also I can get all data with this, or only some bite of data

```
print (lines)
print (lines[0][0])
```

However, I can't get all data with for loop, any idea ?

```
>>> for i in range (0,3):
...     for j in range (0,3):
...         print (lines([i][j])
... 
... 
...
```

Comment: What the the problem with your loop code?  Is it not getting the data from `lines`?

Comment: I suggest you use a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to read the rows of data into your list.

Comment: nothing, I get 3 dots only....
>> for i in range (0,3):
...     for j in range (0,3):
...         print (lines([i][j])
... 
... 
... 
... 
... 
... 
... 
... 
... 
...

Comment: I think, problem is somwhere else in logic or syntax, because I can get data with: print (lines);print (lines[0][0]); print (lines[1][1);

Comment: Does the 3 dots appear everytime you press `enter`?

Comment: yes, every time

Comment: That's just because you are working in a shell like IDLE and you are not pointing to the last row so Python keeps expecting input from you. Simply press the delete keyboard button or the down-arrow to make sure you are at the last prompt row. I suggest you move to a proper IDE like Pycharm instead of using the too-basic IDLE

Comment: Thanks for info, now it suddenly works also without this workaround :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are just experiencing one of the down-sides of using IDLE or a similar Python console. I will try to demonstrate the issue step-by-step.

- The `|` represents the current cursor's location

We start by writing a simple for-loop:

```
>>> for i in range(3):|
```

Now, if we press <kbd>Enter</kbd> **twice**:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...    
...    |
```

Now if we press the Up-arrow and write a print statement:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...    print(i)|
...
```

Now if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again you will just get:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...    print(i)
...    |
...
```

But if you press <kbd>Delete</kbd> you will go back to:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...    print(i)
...    |
```

and now pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will actually execute the loop:

```py
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(i)
...         
0
1
2
```